# Windmill seems to be successfully installed, but doesn't start

Tags: python-2.7, osx-mountain-lion, pip, windmill

I installed windmill on mac (mountain lion) using pip, and it seems to be successful:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ kyskmt$ pip-2.7 install windmill
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): windmill in /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

But windmill doesn't start:

```
MacBook-Pro:site-packages kyskmt$ windmill firefox
-bash: windmill: command not found
```

My question: Should I follow the instructions on this link? 
https://github.com/windmill/windmill/wiki/installing
I don't really want to follow this because it will create another Python install folder, i.e. "/usr/local/bin/python". I'd already installed Python2.7 and pip, as well as many other libraries, using MacPorts (thus, the location is:"/opt/local/bin/python").

Should I install another python and easy_install? Or any other solution to start windmill?

Answer (score 0):

Works very well with default Python on OS X 10.8 and probably even with older versions.

Following the good practice of installing python modules as user instead of root, I installed windmill with `pip install --user windmill`

Obviously you need to be sure that you have `~/Library/Python/2.7/bin/` in your PATH, but that's outside the scope of the question.

If you install it as root it will be on a different directory, find it and add it to the PATH in your bash_profile.